# Set Radiobutton true onItemclick on listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to mark `radio button` true in `listview` `onItemClick` so what I am doing is

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                LinearLayout item_view = (LinearLayout) view;
                final RadioButton itemcheck = (RadioButton) item_view
                        .findViewById(R.id.listview_radiobutton);

                if (itemcheck.isChecked()) {
                    itemcheck.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    itemcheck.setChecked(false);
                }

                itemcheck.setChecked(true);

            }
```

My `listview`

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_margin_15"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/view_margin_15"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_margin_20"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/padding_2"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textFilterEnabled="true"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
```

**Edit:--**

My Adapter code :--

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Details> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Details> transList;
    private LayoutInflater infalInflater;
    private OnCheckedRadioButon onCheckedRadioButon;
    private Typeface mTypeface, mEditTypeface, mPasswdTypeface;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
    private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
    private PromoViewHolder viewHolder;
    public Adapter(Context context, List<Details> mtransList, OnCheckedRadioButon onCheckedRadioButon) {
        super(context, R.layout.dialog_listview, mtransList);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.transList = mtransList;
        this.onCheckedRadioButon = onCheckedRadioButon;
        this.infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;

        try {
             viewHolder = null;

            row = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_listview_code, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.radiobutton = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
            viewHolder.listview_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listview_name);

            setValueText(viewHolder, position);
            viewHolder.radiobutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                    if (checked) {
                        onCheckedRadioButon.onCheckedButton(transList.get(position));
                    }
                }
            });

            viewHolder.radiobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null) {
                        mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                    }

                    mSelectedPosition = position;
                    mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) v;
                }
            });


            if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
                viewHolder.radiobutton.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                viewHolder.radiobutton.setChecked(true);
                if (mSelectedRB != null && viewHolder.radiobutton != mSelectedRB) {
                    mSelectedRB = viewHolder.radiobutton;
                }
            }


            row.setTag(viewHolder);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return row;

    }

    private void setValueText(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.listview_name.setText(transList.get(position).getName());
    }

    public interface OnCheckedRadioButon {
        void onCheckedButton(Details pr);
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        RadioButton radiobutton;
        TextView listview_name;
    }

}
```

It is working but if I click on another position of the `listview` then the previous `radiobutton` position is not unchecked.I want to uncheck all the previous ones and mark only one at a time.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your `ListView` only consist of `RadioButtons`? I would recommend using a `Radiogroup` if that is the case.

Comment: can you post full code of your Adapter? need to track for each item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use POJO classes (Setter or Getter) to manage this type of condition. Use boolean variable in that class and change its values according to the position true or false.

POJO Class Like :

```
public class CheckListSource {       
    public boolean isSelected;

    public boolean isSelected() {
            return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            isSelected = selected;
    }
```

}

In your adapter :

```
private ArrayList<CheckListSource > itemsData;

public ChildListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ChildListResponse> baseResponse) {
    this.itemsData = baseResponse;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

In BindViewHolder Like :

```
viewHolder.checkParentView.setTag(itemsData.get(position));
viewHolder.checkParentView.setOnClickListener(checkedListener);

    private View.OnClickListener checkedListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckListSource childListResponse = (CheckListSource ) v.getTag();
        if (childListResponse.isSelected())
            childListResponse.setSelected(false);
        else
            childListResponse.setSelected(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Comment: exactly try as per on above instruction. it will work.

Comment: @ChiragArora can you show some demo and elaborate it.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please check edited answer and let me know if you want to know more.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a `boolean` array in your `Activity`. Each `boolean` value corresponds to a `RadioButton`.

If a `RadioButton` is checked, set its `boolean` value to `true`, and set all other `boolean` values in the array to `false`.

In the `getView()` of your `Adapter`, call `your_radio_button.setChecked(your_boolean_array[position])`.

Once the `boolean` array is modified, call `your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](http://alumincan-blog.logdown.com/posts/261350-android-set-single-mode-in-custom-listview-with-radio-buttom) it works for me..

```
public class ProgramAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<KeyInformation> {
    private final String TAG = "ProgramAdapter";
    private List<KeyInformation> mList;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
    private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
    private String mUserApllication = "";

    public ProgramAdapter(Context context, List<KeyInformation> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.program_item, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mList = objects;
        mInflater = ( LayoutInflater ) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mUserApllication = Settings.System.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.PROGRAMMABLE_KEY_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.program_item, parent, false);
            holder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.mSeparator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_separator);
            holder.mRadioButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioBtn);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.mRadioButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null){
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                }
                mUserApllication ="";
                mSelectedPosition = position;
                mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) view;
            }
        });
        String userApp = mList.get(position).packageName;
        if(mUserApllication.equals(userApp)) {
            mSelectedPosition = position;
        }

        if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
            holder.mRadioButton.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            holder.mRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            mSelectedRB = holder.mRadioButton;
        }
        holder.mImageView.setImageDrawable(mList.get(position).icon);
        holder.mTextView.setText(mList.get(position).lable);
        if (position == 5) {
            holder.mSeparator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.mSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public int getmSelectedPosition () {
        return mSelectedPosition;
    }
    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView mImageView;
        TextView mTextView;
        TextView mSeparator;
        RadioButton mRadioButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: does this work on itemclick on listview because I have already implemented the clicklistener on radiobutton ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below, it will work.

```
    class Details{

    public boolean isSelect=false;
    }
     public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Details> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Details> transList;
    private LayoutInflater infalInflater;
    private OnCheckedRadioButon onCheckedRadioButon;
    private Typeface mTypeface, mEditTypeface, mPasswdTypeface;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
    private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
    private PromoViewHolder viewHolder;
    public Adapter(Context context, List<Details> mtransList, OnCheckedRadioButon onCheckedRadioButon) {
        super(context, R.layout.dialog_listview, mtransList);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.transList = mtransList;
        this.onCheckedRadioButon = onCheckedRadioButon;
        this.infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         }
    public void updateList(){
        viewHolder.radiobutton.setChecked(false);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;

        try {
             viewHolder = null;

            row = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_listview_code, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.radiobutton = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
            viewHolder.listview_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listview_name);

            setValueText(viewHolder, position);
            viewHolder.radiobutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                    if (checked) {
                        onCheckedRadioButon.onCheckedButton(transList.get(position));
                    }
                }
            });

            viewHolder.radiobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Details detail=transList.get(position);
            for(int i=0;i<transList.size;i++){
                Detail b=transList.get(i);
                b.isSelect=false;
            }
            detail.isSelect=true;
            adapter.notifydatasetchange();
                }
            });

        Details detail=transList.get(position);
            if (detail.isSelect) {
                viewHolder.radiobutton.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                viewHolder.radiobutton.setChecked(false);
            }


            row.setTag(viewHolder);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return row;

    }

    private void setValueText(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.listview_name.setText(transList.get(position).getName());
    }

    public interface OnCheckedRadioButon {
        void onCheckedButton(PromoDetails promoDetails);
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        RadioButton radiobutton;
        TextView listview_name;
    }

}
```